# Cleaner EcmaScript 6 for React state initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a functional React component with an AppContext.  I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way of establishing the state object instead of creating each member outside the object, and then listing them inside.  Perhaps with direct restructuring from the `useState` function.  Example:

```
export function AppProvider() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
    const state = {
        message,
        setMessage,
        errorMessage,
        setErrorMessage
    };

    return (<AppContext.Provider value={state}/>)
}
```

Comment: Looks perfectly reasonable to me

Comment: Ok. You may define an object for all the keys like you did in the state. To define type if you are not using typescript you can use prop-types. and then directly destructure that in Provider.

Comment: Once you have a few dozen repetitions of the useState patterns it looks really messy.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you could look into using a reducer to obtain your state.